# Liferay 6.2, automaticaly create page with specific look and feel

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

try to create programaticaly page with portlet where look and feel is specific [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AxIk.png)

If I set it manualy using liferay UI, i have found out that in liferay database, table LAYOUT.COLORCHEMEID is set value to 01. So i try to do same think programaticaly...

unfortunately using the code it isn't working. I have tried

```
    Layout layout = LayoutLocalServiceUtil.addLayout(
        group.getCreatorUserId(), group.getGroupId(), privateLayout,
        LayoutConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_LAYOUT_ID, name, StringPool.BLANK,
        StringPool.BLANK, LayoutConstants.TYPE_PORTLET, false, friendlyURL,
        serviceContext);
    layout.setColorSchemeId(colorSchemeId);
    LayoutLocalServiceUtil.updateLayout(layout);
```

nor this works

LayoutLocalServiceUtil.updateLookAndFeel(layout.getGroupId(), layout.getPrivateLayout(), layout.getLayoutId(), layout.getThemeId(), colorSchemeId, layout.getCss(), false);

is this a bug in liferay or there is another way how to set specific color scheme?

Comment: the solution of this case is to use
ColorScheme cs = ThemeLocalServiceUtil.getColorScheme(companyId, themeId, colorSchemeIdToSearch, false);

and then layout.setColorSchemeId(cs.getColorSchemeId());

Answer (score 0):

which problem are you trying to solve ? setting the theme or the colorscheme of the theme ? which is kind of a variant of the same portal theme